# Strip only domain name out of input url string

Tags: bash, sed, grep, cut

Did a bit of searching already but cannot seem to find an elegant way of doing this. I'd like to be able to search through a list like below and only end up with a plain text output file containing on the domain name, no http:// or anything after the /

So a list like this:

```
http://7wind.ru/file/Behind+the+dune/
http://aldersgatencsc.org/open.php?utm_source=5r2ke0ow6k&utm_medium=qqod2h9a88&utm_campaign=2d1hl1v8c5&utm_term=mz34ligqc4&utm_content=bgi71kl5oy
http://amunow.org/test.php?utm_source=5r2ke0ow6k&utm_medium=qqod2h9a88&utm_campaign=2d1hl1v8c5&utm_term=dhxg1r4l76&utm_content=tr71txtklp
```

I want to end up with plain text output file like this.

```
7wind.ru
aldersgatencsc.org
amunow.org
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
http://7wind.ru/file/Behind+the+dune/
http://aldersgatencsc.org/open.php?utm_source=5r2ke0ow6k&utm_medium=qqod2h9a88&utm_campaign=2d1hl1v8c5&utm_term=mz34ligqc4&utm_content=bgi71kl5oy
http://amunow.org/test.php?utm_source=5r2ke0ow6k&utm_medium=qqod2h9a88&utm_campaign=2d1hl1v8c5&utm_term=dhxg1r4l76&utm_content=tr71txtklp
```

You can use `cut`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | cut -d'/' -f3
7wind.ru
aldersgatencsc.org
amunow.org
```

Or, if your content is in a file:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f3 file
7wind.ru
aldersgatencsc.org
amunow.org
```

Then redirect that to the file you want:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f3 file >new_file
```

Comment: Thanks this works great and it's short and to the point. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F \/ '{ print $3 }' outputfile > newfile
```

Print the 3rd field delimited by /

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's#.*//([^/]*)/.*#\1#' Input_file
7wind.ru
aldersgatencsc.org
amunow.org
```

Answer (score 0):

try following awks.

**Solution 1st:**

```
awk '{sub(/.*\/\//,"");sub(/\/.*/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:**

```
awk '{match($0,/\/.[^/]*/);print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by stripping the protocol and `://` first, then anything after and including the next slash.

```
sed "s|.*://||; s|/.*||" url-list.txt
```

Add `-i` to change the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this regexp

```
((http|https):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z\.]+)(\/)?
```

first match, 3th group
but it may validate invalid url too! be careful